# Can not access array element in Python comming from Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to cycle through an array in python:

```
# pull all shops into array
selectors = response.xpath('//div[@class="shop"]')
# cycle through all elements
for selector in selectors:
```

Somehow this does not work as it always is accessing the first element. Looking into the xpaths manually I do get the following:

```
>>> selectors = response.xpath('//div[@class="shop"]')
>>> selectors[7].xpath('//a[@class="name"]/@href').extract_first()
'/redirect/id/22216/ppn/1100410330'

# direct access
>>> response.xpath('//div[@class="shop"][8]//a[@class="name"]/@href').extract_first()
'/redirect/id/31/ppn/1100410330'
```

Accessing the element directly (note 8=7 due to 0), I am able to get it. Just cycling through it does not work out.

It cycles correclty n amount of times, but I am always getting the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want `selector.xpath('.//a[@class="name"]/@href').extract_first()`.

Comment: Of course! Stupid me ... Thank you for your help.